# A few questions about parallelization in c#

Tags: c#, parallel-processing

I am writing a heavy web scraper in c#. I want it to be fast and reliable. 
Parallel.Foreach and Parallel.For are way too slow for this.
For the input I am using a list of URLs. I want to have up to 300 threads working at the exact same time (my cpu and net connection can handle this). What would be the best way to do this? Would using tasks work better for this?
Sometimes the threads end for no apparent reason and some of the results don't get saved. I want a more reliable way of doing this. Any ideas?
I want to have a more solid queue type of scraping.
What I came up with (not all code but the important parts):

```
        List <string> input = // read text file
        int total = words.Length;
        int maxThreads = 300;

        while (true)
        {
            if (activeThreads < maxThreads)
            {
               current++;
               Thread thread = new Thread(() => CrawlWebsite(words[current]));
               thread.Start();
            }
        }

        public static void CrawlWebsite(string word)
        {
            activeThreads++;

            // scraping part

            activeThreads--;
        }
```

Comment: activeThreads is not protected, will have racing conditions.

Comment: How did you determine that the two `Parallel` methods are too slow?

Comment: @John Saunders I tried my own example and Parallel.Foreach and compared the results. Parallel.Foreach only runs 2 threads even when setting MaxDegreeOfParallelism to a higher number

Comment: @Zig Mandel I added lock(this) for activeThreads++; and activeThreads--;

Comment: I am not sure if lock is the right way. ++ and -- should be atomic and comparison as well. You can also you Interlocked class. If there is some racing condition you will end with 301 or 299 threads - don´t think this is a problem as you have finite queue. Bug can be in `while (true)` The loop always uses CPU as 100%. It either creates new thread or jumps againt to the beginning. Try to insert Thread.Yield or some sleep there.

Comment: ++ and -- are not atomic at all. The atomic operations are `Interlocked.Increment(` and `Interlocked.Decrement(`. Also, to the OP, what version of .NET are you using and can you please include how you are downloading the data for the scrape, there are [asynchronous methods](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.downloadstringasync.aspx) that are even better than threads for downloading from the internet.

Comment: Did your performance test test `Parallel.ForEach` with your specific workload? In particular, did you try it where each "loop" was a web scrape? Did you test the actual performance, as opposed to counting the number of threads? It's possible that the actual _performance_ would have been no better with more threads, or might actually have been worse.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain You are right, ++ and -- are not atomic. My bad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using System.Threading.ThreadPool. It could be a little faster for your scenario with many threads, as well as you don't need to manage activeThreads. Instead you can use ThreadPool.SetMaxThreads() and SetMinThreads() and the ThreadPool manages the number of parallel threads for you.

BTW, there is missing synchronization of the shared variables in your example. One of the ways how to synchronize access is using "lock" - see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c5kehkcz.aspx

Also your thread-runned method - the CrawlWebsite() should handle ThreadAbortException - see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadabortexception.aspx.

Answer (score 1):

I was recently working on very similar problem and don´t think that using any high number of threads will make it faster. The slowest think is usually downloading the data. Having huge number of threads does not make it faster, because mostly they are waiting for network connections data transfer etc. So I ended up with having two queues. One is handled by some small number of threads that just send async download requests (10-15 requets at a time). The responses are stored into another queue that goes into another thread pool that takes care of parsing and data processing (Number of threads here depends on your CPU and processing algorithm).

I also save all downloaded data to a database. Anytime I want to implement parsing of some new information from the web I don´t need to redownload the content, but only parse the cached web from DB (This saves a looot of time)